# Estimated Cost field is missing in Appengine's new Developer Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

In the old (non-Ajax) Google Appengine's Developer Console Dashboard - showed estimated cost for the last 'n' hours. This was useful to quickly tell how the App engine is doing vis-a-vis the daily budget.

This field seems to be missing in the new Appengine Developer Console. I have tried to search various tabs on the Console and looked for documentation, but without success.

Looking for any pointers as to how do I get to this information in the new Console and any help/pointers are highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

App Engine > Dashboard

This view shows how much you are charged so far during the current billing day, and how many hours you still have until the reset of the day. This is equivalent to what the old console was showing, except there is no "total" line under all charges.

App Engine > Quotas

This view shows how much of each daily quota have been used.

App Engine > Quotas > View Usage History

This view gives you a summary of costs for each of the past 90 days. Clicking on a day gives you a detailed break-down of all charges for that day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not have the same view as the old one. The old view showed intra-day who what resource is being used how much vis-a-vis cost - the same view that is shown on Usage History on the new console.. (they have taken step back in functionality to the end-user with this new and supposedly better console..